# How to know what kind of permission (Full, manage, write) is used for the current App?

Tags: client-object-model, permissions, sharepoint-addin

I planing to build an JavaScript library to manipulate SharePoint Lists and Items , which developer can use with there SharePoint Hosted apps, and I want to publish on CodePlex,

anyway, this JS library can access the items using two ways, and both of them are working fine, but one of them have better performance.

form my library I need to know what kind of permission (Full, manage, write) is used for the current App, and based on that I can run the fit code.

**Update:** My App authorization policy is default (**App-only** policy)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding JS code runs on Client side and uses the permission of current logged in user.

Hence you should check current user permission instead of app permission.

Comment: as you can see in my above quotation I'm asking about CSOM inside  SharePoint Hosted apps. and as I know, in this context the code run under app permission not under user permission

Comment: You said JS library? Or you building a CSOM .Net library?

Comment: @jobin, you can not run js-code as another user (or in app context), it will always run in the permissions of the current user

Comment: CSOM JavaScript is equivalent to JSOM. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx, anyway, it is SharePoint Hosted app, this mean we can use js only

Comment: JSOM can't get elevated as CSOM.

Comment: let's back to question context: How to know what kind of permission (Full, manage, write) is used for the current App (SharePoint hosted app)?

Comment: @jobin I don't believe you can get such info with JSOM.  Besides, this is the app author's job to know this info, and to code accordingly.

Comment: what is the Author role in this scenario?

Comment: @jobin The person who is coding the app...

Comment: yes, but why he should know the permission, what is the relation between permission and user, the question is: SharePoint hosted app have four main permissions on the hosted web (Full, manage, write and Read), using code I need to know what is the app permission, regardless who use it.

Comment: The person coding the app sets the app permissions, so of course he would know the permissions.  It's the developer's job to take permissions and security into consideration, not the js library being used.